# How to convert DFT to DCT

Tags: image-processing, discrete-signals

I've been trying to find a fast 16 point dct2 and dct3 implementation, however I could only find it [in literature](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.3442.pdf) expressed as mathematical equations, which honestly I couldn't understand.

However I did find a [code generator](http://spiral.net/codegenerator.html) that outputs dft transforms. The main problem I have is the DFT and Inverse DFT don't have the same numbers going in and out.

```
// Before DFT              // After DFT and IDFT
inputArray[ 0] = 12;       outputArray[ 0] = 184;
inputArray[ 1] = 12;       outputArray[ 1] = 194;   
inputArray[ 2] = 12;       outputArray[ 2] = 178;
inputArray[ 3] = 14;       outputArray[ 3] = 198;
inputArray[ 4] =  8;       outputArray[ 4] = 155;  
inputArray[ 5] = 10;       outputArray[ 5] = 141;
inputArray[ 6] = 12;       outputArray[ 6] = 164;
inputArray[ 7] = 12;       outputArray[ 7] = 149;
inputArray[ 8] = 12;       outputArray[ 8] = 138;
inputArray[ 9] = 12;       outputArray[ 9] = 121; 
inputArray[10] = 12;       outputArray[10] = 107;
inputArray[11] = 12;       outputArray[11] = 90;
inputArray[12] = 12;       outputArray[12] = 74;  
inputArray[13] = 12;       outputArray[13] = 55;
inputArray[14] = 12;       outputArray[14] = 37;
inputArray[15] = 12;       outputArray[15] = 19;
```

I realized the first 5 or so indexes do equal the inputs when divided by 16, however this trend doesn't continue as you go down.

Is this the expected behavior? Or is there something else I need to do the get a proper conversion?

Also I did find an 8 [point dct](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-discrete-cosine-transform-algorithms) that works well and gives the proper results, is there anyway to expand that into a fast 16 point dct?

Edit:

The reason I want to find a fast 16x16 DCT is because I'm working on a javascript video codec that supports transparency.

So after inter frame prediction is finished I'm left with a lot of residue. Because it's in javascript, and it's processing 24 frames a second I need the fastest way possible to compress and decompress this residue.

Comment: "IDFT(DFT(input))" doesn't need to be "input"; but it MUST be "input times constant". If that's not the case, your DFT or IDFT is broken.  There's nothing to discuss, then, just use an not-broken implementation.

Comment: also, computing a 16-DCT "naively" using the DCT matrix is ... pretty fast on modern computers. For what reasons / applications do you need a faster DCT?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I edited my question to reflect why I need a fast 16x16 dct. I'm not sure what you mean by my must be input "input times constant". Can you explain a little more about that?

Comment: The IDFT, is, as the name suggests, the inverse operation to the DFT; but it depends on the specific definition whether IDFT(DFT(input)) == input or input·constant.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to write a video codec in an interpreted language that fully abstracts the memory model away from its data? JavaScript is especially notorious for not having a proper "vector" data type that has constant access time and contiguous memory – you can basically optimize your algorithm as much as you want, but chances are that the most naive implementation in C++ or C or FORTRAN or … would absolutely outperform what you've done, simply because "handling JavaScript to do some math" is so much more work for your computer than the math that you want to do...

Comment: @MarcusMüller I oversimplified a bit by saying I would use javascript. I'm really going to use web assembly. https://webassembly.org/. I think the DFT and IDFT I used from the generator are just broken, I can't seem to find any mathematical symmetry between the inputs and outputs. Will keep searching, thank you for your help!

Comment: so what language are you compiling to WASM?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't know how to move a conversation to chat, so I'll keep responding in the comments. The encoder is built in c++ and cuda. I'm using cuda to search the entire frame for a matching block, vs normal algorithms just searching in a 256x256 area. This gives me on average 15% better find rates and motion vectors are easy to decode. For the decoder I am writing it in c++. It's main job is primarily just to decode motion vectors and IDCT iframes/residue

Comment: (also, when you really look at libraries that people use to do massive computations like the [FFTw](http://www.fftw.org) (for FFTs), or [VOLK](https://libvolk.org) (for vector operations), you'll notice that such software is dominated by hand-optimized code that carefully trades off complexity for memory bandwidth, minimizes memory hardware cache misses etc – no such thing is achievable with WASM, as it's machine-agnostic)

Comment: so, you're looking for a CUDA DCT, effectively?

Comment: @MarcusMüller no, the cuda is used for block matching only, I can't utilize cuda from wasm. I found an 8 point dct that performs well enough for what I'm trying to do (already ran several test). I don't know if it was hand optimized or not but in code it's just a bunch of add's and some multiplication. https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-discrete-cosine-transform-algorithms However I wanted to test a 16 point dct as I think I would get better compression for the residue

Comment: ok, so CUDA and JavaScript were both red herrings, right? So, you're hand-assembling WASM, are you (yes/no, please).

Comment: No I am not hand assembling wasm. Put simply the only thing I'm converting to wasm is the decoder part of the codec. This decoder is written purely in c++, no cuda invovled.

Comment: ah, OK :) so, C/C++ is the language of interest here! Luckily, that means you can just use about any appropriately licensed MPEG or JPEG source code and use their block-DCT general implementation.

Comment: Don't both of these use 8x8 block sizes though?

Comment: libjpeg-turbo definitely has at least a 16×16 IDCT for fast scaling purposes, but honestly: A 2D-DCT is two loops... I trust your ability to modify an existing one :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Great thank you so much! I'll start digging through the code now to see if I can find it

Comment: I'd really recommend just implementing a 16x16-DCT yourself. Since the 2D-DCT is separable, it's just taking your 16 rows, doing a DCT on each of them (which is really just a (vector·DCT matrix) prodcut), and then taking the resulting 16 rows, and doing the same, but column-wise. Done! It's not very efficient, but you'd have a baseline implementation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes I know how to get a 2d dct from a 1d, but I'm looking for an efficient 1d implementation. Didn't have enough time yet to sit down and look at the turbjpeg library, but I hope to soon

Comment: Problem I see is that you're not working on your hardware, you're compiling for wasm's stack machine. The cleverer your DCT is, the harder it becomes for the transpiler in the browser to optimize what is executed. By trying to be efficient in this tiny 16-point product, you might end up hurting yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which DCT (there are more than four of them), the idea is to take your original data and append to it a mirror-reflection copy of that data.  Now your data is twice as long, and you perform an FFT on twice the length.  but you have some symmetry to it that allows you to toss half of the data in the result of the DFT.

exactly how, depends on if it's DCT I, DCT II, DCT III, DCT IV, or the "MDCT" or whatever is the DCT flavor of the month.

[looks like something useful here.](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/1d-Real_002deven-DFTs-_0028DCTs_0029.html#g_t1d-Real_002deven-DFTs-_0028DCTs_0029)  it may need further exploration.

Comment: So is *the fast DCT*, that is referred in the literature, actually a DCT computed through DFT / FFT like you described here? Or are there particular, independent, methods to compute DCT flowgraphs faster, like DFT / FFT butterflies?

Comment: @Fat32 i think they find ways of doing it without explicitly copying and mirroring the data and doing the FFT of size $2N$.  the people to ask are the [FFTW people](http://www.fftw.org/).  they know everything.

Comment: and @Fat32, i think that there is a preprocessing stage and a postprocessing stage, but what goes in between are FFT butterflies.

Comment: hmm an excerpt from FFTW faq: " Question 4.2: Why is FFTW so fast?
This is a complex question, and there is no simple answer. *In fact, the authors do not fully know the answer, either*...." :-)) Anyway yes that could be. In fact I know about Chen's famous 8 x 8, 16 x 16 DCT2 flowgraphs for Image / Video coding, but I don't how he arrives at them ?